# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to use JSONStore's sync ability with a SQL adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, worklight-adapters

I'm following the document: [05_10_JSONStore_-_Synchronizing_client_and_server_databases.pdf](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_10_JSONStore_-_Synchronizing_client_and_server_databases.pdf)

My adapter retrieves data from an SQL table.
It isn't clear if I need to call the `WL.Client.invokeProcedure()` and where the success/failure callbacks are.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading the latest Getting Started Modules for JSONStore [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html). Specifically:

- [JSONStore - Common JSONStore Usage](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_09_JSONStore_-_Common_JSONStore_Usage.pdf) - See adapter Integration on page 26.
- Download the source code [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip) and take a look at the files under the `adapter` folder, and the HTML+JS files that are part of the Hybrid Application.
- Implementing adapter code is beyond the scope of the JSONStore module, but there are adapter specific modules: [Adapter framework overview](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_01_Adapter_framework_overview.pdf) and [SQL Adapters](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf).
- There is also documentation on IBM InfoCenter for all the methods: [init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_init.html), [load](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_load.html), [push](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_push.html) and a section on [adapter integration](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_wl_adapter_integration.html).

> it isn't clear if i need to call or where the
>   WL.Client.invokeProcedure() and the success/failure callback.

Going back to your question. You can manually call [getPushRequired](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_getpushrequired.html) and then [invokeProcedure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html) to send changes to the adapter or you can use [push](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_push.html) and calling the adapter will be done for you. Similarly, you can call [load](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_load.html) to get data from the adapter, or manually call [invokeProcedure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html) and then [add](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_add.html) to put changes into JSONStore. If you manually call the add method, there's a flag `{push: false}` that will tell JSONStore not to mark the document as "needs to be pushed to the server". If you intend to use the load or push method, you must link the adapter to a collection when you call the [init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_init.html) method.